# Configuring outlook for gmail in proxy network

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, proxy, gmail-imap

I wanted to configure my gmail acount in my outlook 2007 client. I simply followed the instructions @ http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=77689  but seems like these steps do not take into account proxy network . I am just curious if anyone else has succeeded in this. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Are your internet settings setup to use a proxy server, if so, then it should work as it is.

Comment: Yes for the first question & No its not working ..I found few google posts where people tried similar thing and it did not work

Answer (score 3):

Proxies are usually (almost always) there for web traffic only.  The linked article refers to using IMAP protocol, which isn't ordinarily proxied.

The most likely scenario is that your workplace has a web proxy in place, and you are hoping to be able to access your email via Outlook through the web proxy, which isn't going to work.  Direct IMAP access to the outside world is probably not permitted either.

If there actually is an IMAP proxy in place, then the normal method is to use the proxy server address as the server address, then you combine the proxy authentication credentials with the IMAP server credentials in a way that will be specific to the implementation of the proxy.  These would then go into the username and password fields of Outlook account settings (outlook as no internal support for proxied IMAP connections).

Your systems administrators will be able to help you with setting up the credentials correctly, or alternatively find out the proxy make and model and ask for further help here.

Comment: hi Paul, thanks for the information ...how do i ding out the proxy make & model?

Comment: Ask the admins?  Or you could go to http://whatismyip.com and it can sometimes detect the proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am able to find the web proxy IP..but i do not know how to configure IMAP for this proxy

Comment: It is the make and model you are after rather than the IP - but remember, it is very unlikely it will proxy imap.

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully logged in to my gmail account through my office's web proxy, but I am doing this using open SSH port-forwarding feature and going through my home internet connection to do that. I am sure there must be a simpler way, but let me describe how I got this to work:

1. List item
2. Setup cygwin's (or Linux or equivalent) SSH server at home.
3. Setup a port forwarding on your home router for port 22 to your machine with SSH server.
4. Use putty to login to your home computer, using your web proxy's information under the connection/Proxy category on the left pane.
   a. Proxy Type: HTTP 
   b. Proxy hostname: your-web-proxy
   c. Port: your-web-port (typically 80)
   d. Do DNS lookup at proxy end: Yes
   e. Username: your-proxy-username
   f. Password: your-proxy-password
5. Setup a tunnel like this:
   a. Source port: 993
   b. Destination: imap.gmail.com:993
6. Add the e-mail account to outlook using server: localhost, port 996, Use SSL settings.

I suspect you can use cygwin's corkscrew and mkfifo commands to do the same without the need of a SSH server at home, but I just happened to have it already setup so it was simpler for me to do that.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Keypoints to archive this:

1. Have a ssh client which can establish connections through HTTP proxy. I use bitvise for this.
2. setup ssh tunnel

   - 127.0.0.1:993 to imap.gmail.com:993
   - 127.0.0.1:465 to smtp.gmail.com:465
3. Enable less secure app access on https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps
4. add a account in outlook with

   - smtp server: 127.0.0.1:465, protocol ssl, auth required
   - imap server: 127.0.0.1:993, protocol ssl, auth required